# Signal in hopping term in diatomic chain using the tight binding method

Tags: solid-state-physics, atoms, orbitals, tight-binding

I am currently studying the tight binding method, and while solving solving a problem I came across something I don't understand. There are two atoms A and B, A has only type s orbitals and B has only type p orbitals . The problem claims that the hopping term, when atom b with orbital p in the position n jumps to atom A with orbital s in the position n+1 equals to a negative constant -t.
Now the problem asks me to calculate hopping term, when  atom b with orbital p in the position n jumps to atom A with orbital s in the position n-1. According to my teacher the result is the constant t. I am aware that hopping terms from orbitals p to s and s to p are symmetric, but in this case the jump is always from p to s, just in different directions. I tried to solve the integral associated with the hopping term, but I cannot reach any solution. Can please someone help understand this?

PS: I tried to write the integrals in the dirac notation, but I was having a hard time writing, because the code I was writing to create the expression wasnt working. I am sorry!